# Can I tweak Mysql [buffer?] variables to speed up indexes building?

Tags: mysql, performance, index, myisam

I have disabled indexes updates with `alter table my_table disable keys` to speed up inserts

Are there variables I can set [for the session] to speed up indexes rebuilding with `alter table my_table enable keys`? Some specific buffer variables for example

---

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `tec` mediumint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nr` mediumint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fk_brand_trans` smallint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ref_trans` varchar(25) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `fk_coverage_tree` varchar(12) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `ref` varchar(25) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `pos` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  KEY `coverage` (`tec`,`nr`,`fk_coverage_tree`,`fk_brand_trans`),
  KEY `pair` (`fk_brand_trans`,`ref_trans`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci 

+----------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name     | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows      | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time          | Collation         | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+----------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| my_table | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    | 323790932 |             34 | 11315537700 | 281474976710655 |   3792999424 |         0 |           NULL | 2018-07-16 15:57:46 | 2018-07-16 22:19:02 | 2018-07-16 22:19:01 | latin1_general_ci |NULL      |                |         |
+----------+--------+---------+------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+

truncate table my_table;
alter table my_table disable keys;
insert into my_table (...) select ...;
insert into my_table (...) select ...;
insert into my_table (...) select ...;
insert into my_table (...) select ...;
alter table my_table enable keys;
```

Comment: Do you really hope there exists session variables which can afffect on server core processes?

Comment: Yes, allowing specific buffers to use more memory for example

Comment: It can affect on DML queries only.

Comment: How many INSERT..SELECT statements?  About how many rows in each?

Comment: 4 INSERT..SELECT inserting about 150M 150M 6M 2M

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "maybe".

It is *almost* never beneficial to `DISABLE KEYS` and reenable them.  On the assumption you have a valid use case, let's discuss  a specific or two.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW TABLE STATUS` and the statements leading up to the rebuild.

**Some more**

When re-enabling the keys, 11.3GB will be read and about 3.7GB will be written.  (There may be intermediate results, too.)  So, if you are adding a small amount of rows (only a few millions), this is probably slower than updating the indexes as you go.

How much RAM?  What is the value of `key_buffer_size`?  During normal use, that setting should be about 20% of RAM.  But during the `INSERT..SELECTs` and without the pair of `ALTERs`, that should be *temporarily* raised to, say, 80%.  This is because virtually all the random I/O will involve the key_buffer.

Also you *might* get another speed boost by sorting the incoming rows.  That is, it *might* help to do

```
INSERT INTO my_table  SELECT ... ORDER BY `fk_brand_trans`,`ref_trans`
```

(It probably does not matter which index you mimic by the order by.)  The idea here is to 'sequentially' insert rows into one of the indexes while doing random I/O on the other(s).  This might cut in half the I/O to/from the key_buffer -- but at the expense of doing the `ORDER BY`.  There is no way to predict whether this will actually help.

If you could convert to InnoDB, that might improve speed.  However, there are several issues to cover -- lack of `PRIMARY KEY`, disk space might go from 15GB to 40GB, etc.

Comment: Requested info appended

Comment: I will try each of your advices separately and then combine them to each other

Comment: @guigoz - Good.  But keep in mind that combining multiple changes may lead to more (_or less_) benefit than the _sum_ of the individual changes.  I don't have enough info about your data to judge which of my suggestions will or won't help, nor what happens with combinations.

Comment: @guigoz - For example, I can see a scenario where adding ram or sorting the input would _each_ improve performance, yet the combination would improve by the max of the two, not the sum.  And another scenario where _neither_ one helps, yet the combination does help.  (The scenarios involve the relative sizes of the indexes and key_buffer_size.)